# Mappings from sets

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

**Question:**
Let $A = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ and $B = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11\}$. How many injective mappings $f$ from set $A$ to set $B$ are there, such that $f^{-1}$ ($\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}) = \{1,2,3,4\}$?

**My approach:**
There are **$\binom{6}{4}$** ways to map into **$\{1,2,3,4\}$**, and for each choice there are **$4!$**
ways to map them. 
After that I have **$3$** elements left to map into **$\{5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11\}$**. So that would be **$7!/(7−3)!$**

So that would be $\binom{6}{4} \times 4! \times 210 = 18900 $

Any explanation on what i'm doing wrong (if i've made any mistake) will be appreciated.

Comment: Keep track of which is part of your domain and which is part of your codomain.  "*After that I have 3 elements left to map into $\{5,6,7,8,9,10,11\}$*"  Why are $5$ and $6$ still options?

Comment: If I understand correctly i'm mapping 3 elements only to {7,8,9,10,11}  or only 1 to {7,8,9,10,11} ? - @JMoravitz

Comment: You are mapping $\{1,2,3,4\}\subset A$ into $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\subset B$.  "After that I have 3 elements left to map"  Those three elements are the three remaining elements of $A$.  They are $\{5,6,7\}$.  What you map them ***to*** needs to be the remaining elements of !!$B$!! (not $A$).  And the elements of $B$ you have used (or determined will not be used) are $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ so what remains is $\{7,8,9,10,11\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relabing to help fix confusion caused by same named elements appearing in both domain and codomain:

"Let $A=\{a,b,c,d,e,f,g\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11\}$.  How many injective mappings $F$ from $A$ to $B$ are there such that $F^{-1}(\{1,2,3,4,5,6\})=\{a,b,c,d\}$?"

That is... $a$ will map to one of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, $b$ will map to a different one of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and so on... none of $e,f,g$ will map to any of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.  Instead, $e,f,g$ will be mapping to different elements of $\{7,8,9,10,11\}$.

With that correction, you should be on your way to a correct answer given your current work.  I would point out that your manner of presenting the calculations for the different cases was inconsistent.  You could have used falling factorials for both.  You also had an apparent arithmetic mistake which I can't pinpoint.

> $6^{\underline{4}}\times 5^{\underline{3}} = \dfrac{6!}{(6-4)!}\times \dfrac{5!}{(5-3)!} = 360\times 60=21600$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would also love to ask one more question if you can. 
If it was just F (not inverse) would it be F ({a,b,c,d,e,f})={1,2,3,4} ? @JMoravitz

Comment: That would have not been possible for an injective function to have that result so the answer would have been trivially zero... but yes, $F$ maps elements of the domain to elements of the codomain (*or maps subsets of the domain to subsets of the codomain*), while $F^{-1}$ does the opposite, mapping elements of the codomain to elements of the domain (*or subsets of codomain to subsets of domain*).  It is worth also emphasizing that $F^{-1}$ here is to be interpreted as the inverse relation noting that this is not in fact a function here (*as it fails to be everywhere defined*).